# Custom html attributes

Tags: html, angularjs, attributes

I've seen attributes like `ui:some_random_name` and `ng:some_random_name` used by angular js (and jquery UI i guess).

the html spec doesn't seem to allow any non-standard attributes. how come these libraries can get away with it?

Comment: Can you give examples of them in jQuery UI/Angular?

Comment: there are a few on http://angularjs.org/. and most angularjs questions here have them

Answer (score 1):

It's valid within the XML spec which states "[Definition: A Name is a token beginning with a letter or one of a few punctuation characters, and continuing with letters, digits, hyphens, underscores, **colons**"

http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xml-20001006#NT-Name

And Angular accepts the colon as one of the matches it will swap out for directives.

http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Please do [not add a signature](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) to your answer :) .